# How do you choose the constant when using Markov's Inequality?

Tags: algorithms

Markov's Inequality states that `P(X >= a) <= E(X)/a` , for any `a > 0`.  How is a relevant `a` picked?  I was reading up on Count-Min Sketches, and [this](http://www.corelab.ece.ntua.gr/courses/ds.grad/count-min.ppt) powerpoint says that they "use `e` to minimize space used."  How was that arrived at?

**Context and fair disclosure:**

I am supposed to prove that, for count-min sketches, `P(V_i >= f_i + eN / w) <= 1/e`, where `V_i` is a random variable equal to the estimated frequency of element `x_i`, `e` is the base of the natural logarithm, `N` is the total number of keys, and `w` is the number of buckets.  The question hints at using Markov's Inequality, but I don't understand where `e` came from.

Comment: You don't pick specific 'a'. It's true for all a > 0.

Comment: By optimizing a one-variable function. This question belongs on the math or CS StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

To see where e comes from, let's assume instead we pick some arbitrary constant k and use that instead of e.  Then ultimately you will arrive at an expression like this one:

> P(U<sub>i</sub> ≥ f<sub>i</sub> + kN / w) ≤ (1 / k)<sup>d</sup>

Here, U<sub>i</sub> is the estimate of the frequency of x<sub>i</sub>, N is the total number of elements, w is the width of any  array, and d is the number of arrays you use.

Take any ε and δ in the range (0, 1).  Then if you set

> w = k / ε
>
> d = -log<sub>k</sub> δ

You get

> P(U<sub>i</sub> ≥ f<sub>i</sub> + εN) ≤ δ

The question is what choice of k to make that minimizes space usage.  The space usage is given by

> wd = (k / ε) (-log<sub>k</sub> δ)

You can use some elementary calculus to show that this function minimizes when you set k = e.

Hope this helps!